# Using Selenium to run on localhost asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, selenium, automated-tests

I have a asp.net mvc app. I want to test using Selenium. I have a very basic test just top open browser and navigate to `http://localhost:50855/`, but I am getting this error

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

here is my test its very basic

```
Public Sub OpenBrowser()
    driverGC = New ChromeDriver()
    driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:50855/")
End Sub
```

What I would like to know can Selenium fireup IIS or do I have to do it?

I am following [this](http://www.filipekberg.se/2014/01/30/test-automation-web-applications/) which makes me think I don't need to or would it matter I have my tests in a different project in the solution

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Selenium won't start your webserver. It's just driving a browser. You'll need a bit of code to get your site listening before you start 'driving'.

Comment: You need to open 2 instances of VS. In first one, run your application and in the second one, run your tests.

Comment: @Akshay, there must be a better way to do this than start two instances of visual studio ?